# VS Code, Python 3.11 -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.11

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по запуску скриптов python с selenium:
Я создала виртуальное окружение, именно туда установила selenium и webdriver, но при попытке запуска скрипта выходит вот такая ошибка:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'` 
при том, что если я запускаю python в терминале и прописываю скрипт в нем, - все отрабатывает как нужно.

python 3.11, selenium 4.10.0, MacOS Ventura 13.2.1
запускаюсь в VS Code

Comment: Если точно установили внутрь виртуального окружения, но выдает ошибку, значит запускаете не из виртуального окружения. Укажите, как именно запускаете. Если используете расширение Code Runner - отключите или удалите, оно ничего не знает про виртуальные окружения.

Comment: Да, действительно, поняла в чем была ошибка. В качестве интерпретатора был выбран python на компьютере, а не в виртуальном окружении. 
Возможно кому-то поможет: 
Нажать Ctrl+Shift + P, набрать Python: Select Interpreter
Указать нужный путь к python.exe в папке окружения env